# SQL return column based on other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have

```
SELECT col, col1 from table
CASE
WHEN other_col = 'Canada' THEN  1
    ELSE 2
END AS col2
```

it works fine, but i want to calculate

`col3` based on value from `col2`

it should be simple `col3` = value from `col2 / 2`
and return it in the same `select`

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the column `col2` in an expression like `col2 / 2` inside the same select statement. 
You can repeat the same CASE statement like this:

```
SELECT 
  col, 
  col1, 
  CASE WHEN other_col = 'Canada' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS col2
  CASE WHEN other_col  = 'Canada' THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END AS col3
FROM table
```

or by nesting the SELECT statement inside another:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  t.col2 / 2 AS col3
FROM (
  SELECT 
    col, 
    col1, 
    CASE WHEN other_col = 'Canada' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS col2
  FROM table 
) AS t
```

Comment: i can't use `col2` before CASE because it doesn't  exist it table

Comment: I know it does not exist in the table and both above queries work. col2 is an alias of the calculated column. You can't use it in the 1st query to create col3. You must repeat the case statement. In the 2nd query you can use col2 because it exists in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use the alias is because of the 'all at once' expression evaluation.
Expressions are not evaluated in order, but 'all at once' which also allows you to do things like

```
UPDATE Table SET Col1 = Col2, Col2 = Col1...
```

Which would not be possible if the expressions were processed in order.

IMHO it's easier and clearer to use CTE instead of repeating the CASE.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT col, col1, CASE
                  WHEN other_col = 'Canada' 
                    THEN  1
                  ELSE 2
                  END AS col2
FROM table
)
SELECT *, <Whatever Function On (Col2).
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join in Postgres:

```
SELECT t.col, t.col1, v.col2
FROM table t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN other_col = 'Canada' THEN  1 ELSE 2 END)
     ) v(col2);
```

You can then use `v.col2` to your heart's delight in any other expression you want to.